# How can i demonstrate that a file has been uploaded from the selected element on a table in a dashboard

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, accessibility

So, I have the following table on a dashboard that i'm trying to design in order certain process for the place where i work.
On it, I have a few fields (promoter's full name, legal terms, number, uploaded files and commentaries)

Is there a way to show the user that some file has been uploaded for the row of the selected promoter? This file will be a .zip file that contains several PDFs from the promoter.

I have the idea of using an upload icon (as the image suggest), but I don't know if this looks user friendly. Even with that, how can I show that a file has already been added on the promoter's row?

[image: Table that has several rows with information about a promoter's full name, legal terms, number, uploaded files and commentaries]

My idea was to change the color of the icon, but in my opinion it doesn't fit so well :/

[image: Uploadable files column that shows one icon on black color and another one on green]

Comment: Uploaded or downloaded? Your column reads "Downloadable", but your question says "uploaded"

Comment: I would avoid the folder icon with an arrow. That's commonly accepted as being able to upload or download a file (an action) as opposed to meaning a file is available.  The black/green color example would fail accessibility for [WCAG 1.4.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#use-of-color) since the only way to tell the difference between the two icons is with color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dropbox](https://help.dropbox.com/sync/sync-icons) uses icons to show the sync status of its files:

[image]

#### Available

[image]

#### In progress

[image]

Comment: Note that this example is accessible because it uses a different icon symbol **in addition to** color.  It would not fail WCAG 1.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you can augment the field that shows the upload status to be more clear. I used Google's uploading style for both Gmail and GDrive as a reference.

[image: uploading file]

The idea is that you show yellow for in-progress and then green with the word done when uploaded. With this configuration, the user gets the entire picture with minimal mental work.